# Managing a list of users in Mysql (in a secure way)

Tags: java, mysql

I'm currently writing a Java application where users would connect using authentication information (nickname+password).

Any suggestion concerning the way of **storing the list of users and their authentication information** using MySQL, in order to **control access to data based on user identity**?

I also worry about security.

Comment: Have you considered using an existing Java CMS that comes with built-in or pluggable user management/permission system, probably a lot more advanced than what you could write from scratch?

Comment: I don't understand your question. ` where users would connect using authentication information`. Your users would connect where? MySQL server? MySQL has its own access control.

Comment: Create a cryptography code/function which will crypt the user data before storing in the database and if you would like to retrieve it, then use the decryption and then return the values.

Comment: Do you want to give access to the databes to users?

Comment: @pedromss I'm actually looking for the best way to do this. I've tried to store the user list and all their  information in a table, and then verify the autentification information at each connection using java, but I guess this wouldn't be secured at all.

Comment: @Cratylus they would connect to the app. 
  Actually there is only one database which contains all the data, and all users would have access to it, since the app is directly using that db. But i prefer if I could specify which tables each user can access, so that this would be more secure.

Comment: @marekful never heard of that. Which java cms do you suggest?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20cms%20user%20management%20system&rct=j

Comment: @Muselc:`But i prefer if I could specify which tables each user can access`. You can in MySQL access rights

Comment: @Cratylus So basically the users of my app would be MySQL users? I wonder if this is a good approach.

Comment: @Muselc:Security wise you *must* define access rights to your tables especially if you expose them to the network (actually you should not even be doing that if your concern is about security). Then your users connect and have the rights needed *per* table